# Difference between *ptr += 1 and *ptr++ in C

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

I just started to study C, and when doing one example about passing pointer to pointer as a function's parameter, I found a problem.

This is my sample code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* allocateIntArray(int* ptr, int size){
    if (ptr != NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            ptr[i] = i;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}

void increasePointer(int** ptr){
    if (ptr != NULL){
        *ptr += 1; /* <----------------------------- This is line 16 */
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* p1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* 10);
    allocateIntArray(p1, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d\n", p1[i]);
    }

    increasePointer(&p1);
    printf("%d\n", *p1);
    p1--;
    free(p1);
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem occurs in line 16, when I modify `*ptr+=1` to `*ptr++`. The expected result should be the whole array and number 1 but when I use `*ptr++` the result is 0.

Is there any diffirence between `+=1` and `++`? I thought that both of them are the same.

Comment: Note that the given code won't compile as you haven't declared `string`.

Comment: Other notes: 1) `allocateIntArray` is a bad name as it seems you `malloc` the array from the function, but you don't. I suggest `fillIntArray` instead. 2) You don't utilize the return value of `allocateIntArray`. I suggest you change  the return type to `void`. 3) Shouldn't `if (ptr != NULL)` in function `increasePointer` be `if (*ptr != NULL)`? 4) The cast in `malloc` is unneccessary. See Sourav's comment above. 5) This: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ printf("%d\n", p1[i]); }` and `printf("%d\n", *p1); p1--;` needs to be enclosed in `if(p1 != NULL)`. 6) `string.h` is unused.

Comment: Related: [++ on a dereferenced pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859770/on-a-dereferenced-pointer-in-c)

Comment: `p+=1` is like `++p`, not like `p++`

Comment: this question was asked 4 years ago: [Is ++ the same as += 1 for pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421041/is-the-same-as-1-for-pointers)

Comment: @ren Almost, but not quite. The linked question doesn't involve the dereference operator, which is the crux of the OP's issue here.

Comment: There's one common thing about the two expressions: **do** use paranthesis! At least for the second one... If people reading some code wonder what the precedence it, then you've done it wrong.

Comment: This is why I always use parentheses for everything. Memorizing operator precedence is only useful for code golf.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

The difference is due to operator precedence.

The post-increment operator `++` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`. So `*ptr++` is equivalent to `*(ptr++)`. In other words, the post increment modifies the pointer, not what it points to.

The assignment operator `+=` has lower precedence than the dereference operator `*`, so `*ptr+=1` is equivalent to `(*ptr)+=1`. In other words, the assignment operator modifies the value that the pointer points to, and does not change the pointer itself.

Comment: For beginners, a mnemonic is the similarity between `*p++` and `*++p`. Operator precedence of the latter is clear, the one of the former follows.

Answer (score 23):

The order of precedence for the 3 operators involved in your question is the following :

post-increment `++` > dereference `*` > assignment `+=`

You can check this [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for further details on the subject.

> When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it. For example, the expression `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`, and not as `(*p)++`.

Long story short, in order to express this assignment `*ptr+=1` using the post-increment operator you need to add parentheses to the dereference operator to give that operation precedence over `++` as in this **`(*ptr)++`**

Comment: Interesringly, this is currently the only answer which contains solution... (*ptr)++

Answer (score 7):

Let's apply parentheses to show the [order of operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

```
a + b / c
a + (b/c)
```

Let's do it again with

```
*ptr   += 1
(*ptr) += 1
```

And again with

```
*ptr++
*(ptr++)
```

- In `*ptr += 1`, we increment the value of the variable our pointer *points* to.
- In `*ptr++`, we increment the pointer *after* our entire statement (line of code) is done, and return a reference to the variable our pointer *points* to.

The latter allows you to do things like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // Copy value from *src and store it in *dest
    *dest++ = *src++;

    // Keep in mind that the above is equivalent to
    *(dest++) = *(src++);
}
```

This is a common method used to copy a `src` array into another `dest` array.

Comment: "and return a reference to the variable our pointer points to." C doesn't have references.

Comment: @MilesRout Perhaps calling it an lvalue might be more accurate? But I'm not sure how to put it without adding jargon.

Answer (score 4):

Very good question.

In K&R "C programming language" "5.1 Pointers and Addresses", we can get an answer for this.

"The unary operators * and & bind more tightly than arithmetic operators"

```
*ptr += 1      //Increment what ptr points to.
```

"Unary operators like * and ++ associate **right to left**."

```
*ptr++        //Increment prt instead of what ptr point to.
```

//It works like *(ptr++).

The correct way is:

```
(*ptr)++      //This will work.
```

Comment: This is the first time I comment on Stack Overflow. I have updated the format of the code.^^ Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

*ptr += 1 : Increment data that ptr points to.
*ptr++ : Increment pointer that is point to next memory location instead of the data that pointer points to.